# Disallow & prevent ALL data access (2G 3G ) for user (maybe even WiFi) directly or via MDM?

Tags: internet, mobile-data, data-connection

I saw this similar question but it does not ask or answer what I am asking.
[How to totally block internet access (data) on an Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88369/how-to-totally-block-internet-access-data-on-an-android)
Completely block disable "data" period so that user cannot enable it or use it.

[How can I disable mobile data completely?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64918/how-can-i-disable-mobile-data-completely?rq=1)
Some of the answers here seem like good options, but I need a way where OTA/ SIM updates or the user/ employee cannot work/ hack around it easily.
Can any of these answers be applied in a way where it cant be easily reversed?

**Completely disable & prevent 2G 3G ALL data access/ use (maybe even WiFi) on Android directly or via MDM?**

There have been cases of some people I know (older family) that were brought an Android phone but inadvertently some Data was used without a Data Plan - more expensive.

Lets say instead of buying Feature Phones for some delivery boys, we bought Cheapest Android phones possible - The boss there just wants Phone calls with them and wants to ensure the boys wont be able to Rack up Data use/ bills on the phone -

Are there ways to Disable Data AND/ OR WiFI? Selectively or so? Maybe only have it on when being configured by MDM?

We will need the SIM to ensure Calls & SMS work. Is there a way to disable data use?

Comment: Why not just get your carrier to give you SIMs that only support voice calling?

Comment: Carriers not co operative. As I mentioned above, despite old people not wanting data, carrier wants to charge them for mistaken use