# Marshmallow: Changing and connecting to an APN

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, vpn, cellular-radio, apn, android-one

Okay, before anyone can downvote this or anything silly, I need to clarify a few things:

1. This is for Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)
2. I'm using a FlashFire-Rooted Cherry Mobile One (technically called Android One Sprout8)
3. Prior to upgrading into Marshmallow, I am able to do these steps.
4. This is not a duplicate of [this particular ticket](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149026/data-disabled-via-dummy-apn-data-connection-toggle-how-to-prevent-changes) or [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146400/disallow-prevent-all-data-access-2g-3g-for-user-maybe-even-wifi-directly?rq=1), please.

**Scenario** 
I want to use a certain APN (for a certain cellular network) which does not connect to the internet without a corresponding VPN. To do that, in the previous versions of Android, I simply create an APN with the corresponding configurations, switch to it by tapping the radio button, then the Android system connects to that APN, even if it can't connect to the common internet.

In Marshmallow, ([or at least the stock ROM I flashed?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/ota-android-one-marshmallow-t3225311)) this doesn't work, and the it connects to the default network APN. It's similar to how my other phone, ZenFone 2, works, but with LTE (always defaulting to the nearest working APN; otherwise HSPA+ works.)

Is there some way to force the APN into this system? But I wouldn't want to downright delete my old APNs, as I still would want to connect to them when needed.

Comment: In APN type, did you write default,supl Means default APN

Comment: unfortunately, yes. It still defaults to the usual APN. Should I try deleting that instead on all the other APNs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insight of user157947 though, I found something that helped:

I set all the Bearers in all my other APNs to something jibberish (not applicable in my country, like IS95A). I haven't seen this feature in Lolipop though (it was only LTE iirc)

To set it back to the original APN, set the Bearer to Unspecified then set your custom APN to IS95A.

I think I can also use this feature as well to force a custom APN on LTE on Marshmallow.

Comment: give it a go, if anything goes wrong you can always reset to default

Comment: Also, Wifi tether or HotSpot changes the apn on some networks